Is there an equivalent of the "Z" module in Linux terminal to navigate easily?
For PowerShell "Z" module is very helpful and Save time typing out directory path by jumping around instead.
Do we have equivalent of "Z" in Linux terminal? or Similiar which can search in the history and give you multiple options in list which you can choose using arrow keys..
In Powershell "Z" can be installed using
Install-Module -Name Z -Force -Scope CurrentUser


https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/z/1.1.14
https://github.com/badmotorfinger/z


It's a port of the z bash shell script - so find the bash version?

Yes, there are tons of packages for various distros and shells, but this will be closed as it's software recommendation request, plus it lacks basic info like the shell yo're using in the 1st place

https://askubuntu.com/questions/250012/how-do-i-install-z-script

Haven't used Z in PowerShell, but I have the feeling you're asking for something fzf-based. Fzf itself is mainly a generic 'menu' tool but it comes with various shell integrations prepackaged, e.g. for Bash's cd Tab completion as well as its Ctrl-R history search. After installing it, see the shell integration section.
